# C# read the name of the connected microphone

Tags: c#, microphone, recording

How can I read in a winform the names of the connected recording device and of the standard recording device?

Comment: WMI is a good bet.  This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36159760/enumerate-audio-input-devices-with-wmi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use WMI.Here's a good starting point:[Administering windows machine programmatically](http://www.cshandler.com/2013/03/administering-windows-machine.html)

```
public static void Main()
{
  try
  {
     ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2","SELECT * FROM Win32_SoundDevice");

     foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
     {
         Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
         Console.WriteLine("List of sound cards installed");
         Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
         Console.WriteLine("ProductName: {0}", queryObj["ProductName"]);
         Console.WriteLine("Availability: {0}", queryObj["Availability"]);
         Console.WriteLine("Caption: {0}", queryObj["Caption"]);
         Console.WriteLine("ConfigManagerErrorCode: {0}", queryObj["ConfigManagerErrorCode"]);
         Console.WriteLine("ConfigManagerUserConfig: {0}", queryObj["ConfigManagerUserConfig"]);
         Console.WriteLine("CreationClassName: {0}", queryObj["CreationClassName"]);
         Console.WriteLine("Description: {0}", queryObj["Description"]);
         Console.WriteLine("DeviceID: {0}", queryObj["DeviceID"]);
         Console.WriteLine("DMABufferSize: {0}", queryObj["DMABufferSize"]);
         Console.WriteLine("ErrorCleared: {0}", queryObj["ErrorCleared"]);
         Console.WriteLine("ErrorDescription: {0}", queryObj["ErrorDescription"]);
         Console.WriteLine("InstallDate: {0}", queryObj["InstallDate"]);
         Console.WriteLine("LastErrorCode: {0}", queryObj["LastErrorCode"]);
         Console.WriteLine("Manufacturer: {0}", queryObj["Manufacturer"]);
         Console.WriteLine("MPU401Address: {0}", queryObj["MPU401Address"]);
         Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", queryObj["Name"]);
         Console.WriteLine("PNPDeviceID: {0}", queryObj["PNPDeviceID"]);
         Console.WriteLine("PowerManagementSupported: {0}", queryObj["PowerManagementSupported"]);
         Console.WriteLine("Status: {0}", queryObj["Status"]);
         Console.WriteLine("StatusInfo: {0}", queryObj["StatusInfo"]);
         Console.WriteLine("SystemCreationClassName: {0}", queryObj["SystemCreationClassName"]);
         Console.WriteLine("SystemName: {0}", queryObj["SystemName"]);
     }
 }
 catch (ManagementException e)
 {
    Console.WriteLine("An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " + e.Message);
 }
 }
```

Source:[C# - Enumerate audio devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36159760/enumerate-audio-input-devices-with-wmi)